# How can you set transaction_isolation = READ-COMMITTED on an openshift MySql database?

Tags: mysql, jboss, openshift

I have a JBOSS scaleable server running on one (or more) gear(s), running against a MySQL database on a second gear. I would like to set

```
transaction_isolation = READ-COMMITTED
```

I can ssh to the JBOSS server, but if I look at /etc/my.cnf file it's on the wrong gear (I am assuming) and I can't figure out how to ssh to the MySql gear. And anyway that file is root user file protected and wont let me change anything.

phpMyAdmin is apparently not supported on a scaleable machine.

I cant find any information about environment variables that would help.

Comment: Have you read the manual chapter titled [SET TRANSACTION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/set-transaction.html)?  You can set the transaction isolation level on a per-session basis—perhaps this is all you require?

Comment: Thanks, eggyal. I am accessing the database via JPA. I dont think that is doable via JPA.... or am I (hopefully) mistaken?

Comment: Turns out this was easy-peasy: all I needed to do was `em.createNativeQuery("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED").executeUpdate();` Thanks again to @eggyal - you saved the day

Comment: @Ari feel free to answer (and accept) your own question, so that future StackOverflow users can benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to set it at the database level, but thanks to @eggyal I got the idea to set it programmatically. In the transactions where it was important that it be set I called 
`em.createNativeQuery("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED").executeUpdate();`
at the start of the transaction. 
(My application is a JPA application, Hiberate implementation, MySql backend)